# Sanitizing file & directory form input

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm looking to sanitize admin form input for update_option.  The input is for a directory path and file name. The input will look like this:

/directory/subdirectory/

and

/thisfile.min.js

So far, every sanitize I've tried strips out the forward slashes.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you would want to use is [`sanitize_text_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) which among other things, strips all HTML tags, and remove line breaks, tabs and extra white space.

```php
// This worked fine for me - I got /directory/subdirectory/
$value = sanitize_text_field( '/directory/subdirectory/' );

// And so does this one - I got /thisfile.min.js
$value = sanitize_text_field( '/thisfile.min.js' );

// Even with an actual form input (e.g. <input name="my_field">),
// the function worked just fine (using the same data as above).
$value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['my_field'] );
```

So have you already tried that function and are you sure it stripped the `/`? How about the other similar functions [listed here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data#Sanitizing:_Cleaning_User_Input)?

Comment: Thanks. Knew about sanitize_text_field but I was so focused on the fact this was being stored as an option that it never popped into my head. I was going through various sanitize_option and failing to find one that worked and actually sanitized.